# Does this question on observed animal choices in a binary decision tree belong on math.SE?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

I am conducting biological research on animal behavior. I have an experimental design that looks to me awfully like a math problem. I don't know if it is suitable for the math.SE and I have problems with phrasing it, especially in a math.SE-friendly way. How best could it be improved before posting it as a question?

### The draft of the question:

There is an arena set up like a binary tree. End nodes are sources of food (e.g. smells) or stimuli that can mix. The animal (or a group of animals) enters the arena from the top, and navigates and makes choices based on the stimuli that reach it, always making a binary choice at each node, until it reaches the lowest node. The animal at first finds itself in a complex mixture, and at each fork makes a choice between simpler mixtures. A visual aide:

[image]

The arena size (binary tree height) is not specified yet, it will be around 2, 3 or 4. The idea is to understand or disambiguate the contribution of each of the smells by which choice an animal makes, at every fork of the tree, and where it ends up eventually. The end nodes will be randomized repeatedly and information will be collected about the choices an individual or group of animals make within this arena multiple times.

**Question: what kind of statistics or math or tools can be used to understand the 'weight' or contribution of each end node to the observed animal choices?** It seems to me the design of the experiment allows for several mathematical/statistical approaches. Unfortunately I do not know where to begin or what to even describe this problem as to learn more about it.

Comment: Not addressing whether or not it's a fit here, but it sounds like it might go over better on https://stats.stackexchange.com/ .

Comment: I'd expect anyone who advises you on what "statistics or math tools can be used" to first inquire what the experimental hypothesis is.